# PowerShell BizTalk scripts WITHOUT using BizTalk provider for PowerShell

Tags: powershell, biztalk

I have been using the excellent BizTalk Provider for PowerShell from Codeplex for a while now. However in my new company the build team are not comfortable using it so I need to rewrite all my handy configuration scripts to not use it.

I have re-done most of them but am having some problems finding examples of how to do the following two things:

1. Create host instances
2. Create send/receive adapter handers

Can anyone point me to examples of how to do these things WITHOUT the PowerShell provider for BizTalk please? I have done some looking and it seems like everyone uses this now.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't the real issue here the reluctance to use the BizTalk PowerShell provider, when you can use custom scripting? What are the objections?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK here are my finished hacky powershell functions if anyone else needs them:

```
function write-WarnMessage([string]$message) {
    Write-Host $(Get-Date) $message -ForegroundColor Yellow
}

function write-SucessMessage([string]$message) {
    Write-Host $(Get-Date) $message -ForegroundColor Green
}

function write-InfoMessage([string]$message) {
    Write-Host $(Get-Date) $message -ForegroundColor Blue -BackgroundColor White
}

function write-ErrorMessage ([string]$message) {
    Write-Host $(Get-Date) $message -ForegroundColor Red
}

# Gets the execution directory
function Get-ScriptDirectory 
{
    $Invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 1).Value
    Split-Path $Invocation.MyCommand.Path
}

function Delete-Bts-Receive-Handler ( [string]$adapter, [string]$hostName )
{   
    try
    {
        [System.Management.ManagementObject]$objHandler = get-wmiobject 'MSBTS_ReceiveHandler' -namespace 'root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer' -filter "HostName='$hostName' AND AdapterName='$adapter'"
        $objHandler.Delete()
        write-SucessMessage "Deleted $adapter receive handler for $hostName"
    }
    catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException]
    {
        if ($_.Exception.Message -eq "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.")
        {
            write-WarnMessage "$adapter receive handler for $hostName does not exist"
        }
        elseif ($_.Exception.Message.IndexOf("Cannot delete a receive handler that is used by") -ne -1)
        {
            write-WarnMessage "$adapter receive handler for $hostName is in use. Cannot delete."
        }
        else
        {
            write-Error "$adapter receive handler for $hostName could not be deleted: $_.Exception.ToString()"
        }
    }
}

function Delete-Bts-Send-Handler ( [string]$adapter, [string]$hostName )
{
    try
    {
        [System.Management.ManagementObject]$objHandler = get-wmiobject 'MSBTS_SendHandler2' -namespace 'root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer' -filter "HostName='$hostName' AND AdapterName='$adapter'"
        $objHandler.Delete()
        write-SucessMessage "Deleted $adapter send handler for $hostName"
    }
    catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException]
    {
        if ($_.Exception.Message -eq "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.")
        {
            write-WarnMessage "$adapter send handler for $hostName does not exist"
        }
        elseif ($_.Exception.Message.IndexOf("Cannot delete a send handler that is used by") -ne -1)
        {
            write-WarnMessage "$adapter send handler for $hostName is in use. Cannot delete."
        }
        else
        {
            write-Error "$adapter send handler for $hostName could not be deleted: $_.Exception.ToString()"
        }
    }
}

function Delete-Bts-Instance( [string]$hostName, [string]$Server )
{
    try
    {
        # Unintall
        [System.Management.ManagementObject]$objHostInstance = ([WmiClass]"root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer:MSBTS_HostInstance").CreateInstance()
        $name = "Microsoft BizTalk Server " + $hostName + " " + $Server
        $objHostInstance["Name"] = $name
        $objHostInstance.Uninstall()

        # Unmap
        [System.Management.ManagementObject]$objServerHost = ([WmiClass]"root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer:MSBTS_ServerHost").CreateInstance()
        $objServerHost["HostName"] = $hostName
        $objServerHost["ServerName"] = $Server
        $objServerHost.Unmap()

        write-SucessMessage "Deleted host instance for $hostName on $Server"
    }
    catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException]
    {
        write-Error "$hostName host instance on server $Server could not be deleted: $_.Exception.ToString()"
    }
}

function Stop-Bts-HostInstance ( [string] $HostName, [string] $Server )
{
    try
    {
        $filter = "HostName = '" + $HostName + "' and RunningServer = '" + $Server + "'"
        $HostInstance = get-wmiobject "MSBTS_HostInstance" -namespace "root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer" -filter $filter
        $HostInstanceState = $HostInstance.GetState().State

        write-InfoMessage "Current state of $HostName instance on server $Server : $HostInstanceState (1=Stopped, 2=Start pending, 3=Stop pending, 4=Running, 8=Unknown)"

        if ($HostInstanceState -eq 4) 
        {
            $HostInstance.Stop() 
            $HostInstanceState = $HostInstance.GetState().State
            write-SucessMessage "New state of $HostName instance on server $Server: $HostInstanceState (1=Stopped, 2=Start pending, 3=Stop pending, 4=Running, 8=Unknown)"
        }
        else
        {
            $HostInstanceState = $HostInstance.GetState().State
            write-WarnMessage "Failed to stop host instance $HostName on server $Server because host instance state $HostInstanceState was not the expected value of 4 (running)"
        }
    }
    catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException]
    {
        write-Error "$hostName host instance could not be stopped on $Server : $_.Exception.ToString()"
    }
}

function Delete-Bts-Host ( [string]$hostName )
{
    # TODO: This only works intermittently

    try
    {
        [System.Management.ManagementObject]$objHostSetting = get-wmiobject 'MSBTS_HostSetting' -namespace 'root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer' -filter "HostName='$hostName'"
        $objHostSetting.Delete()
        write-SucessMessage "Deleted host $hostName"
    }
    catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException]
    {
        write-Error "$hostName host could not be deleted: $_.Exception.ToString()"
    }
}

# function to create BizTalk host
function Create-Bts-Host(
    [string]$hostName, 
    [int]$hostType, 
    [string]$ntGroupName, 
    [bool]$authTrusted, 
    [bool]$tracking, 
    [bool]$32BitOnly)
{
    try
    {
        [System.Management.ManagementObject]$objHostSetting = ([WmiClass]"root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer:MSBTS_HostSetting").CreateInstance()

        $objHostSetting["Name"] = $hostName
        $objHostSetting["HostType"] = $hostType
        $objHostSetting["NTGroupName"] = $NTGroupName
        $objHostSetting["AuthTrusted"] = $authTrusted
        $objHostSetting["IsHost32BitOnly"] = $32BitOnly 
        $objHostSetting["HostTracking"] = $tracking

        $putOptions = new-Object System.Management.PutOptions
        $putOptions.Type = [System.Management.PutType]::CreateOnly;

        [Type[]] $targetTypes = New-Object System.Type[] 1
        $targetTypes[0] = $putOptions.GetType()

        $sysMgmtAssemblyName = "System.Management"
        $sysMgmtAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName($sysMgmtAssemblyName)
        $objHostSettingType = $sysMgmtAssembly.GetType("System.Management.ManagementObject")

        [Reflection.MethodInfo] $methodInfo = $objHostSettingType.GetMethod("Put", $targetTypes)
        $methodInfo.Invoke($objHostSetting, $putOptions)

        write-SucessMessage "Host $hostName created"
    }
    catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException]
    {
        write-Error "$hostName host could not be created: $_.Exception.ToString()"
    }
}

function Update-Bts-Host ( 
    [string]$hostName, 
    [int]$hostType, 
    [string]$ntGroupName, 
    [bool]$authTrusted, 
    [bool]$tracking, 
    [bool]$32BitOnly)
{
    try
    {
        [System.Management.ManagementObject]$objHostSetting = ([WmiClass]"root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer:MSBTS_HostSetting").CreateInstance()

        $objHostSetting["Name"] = $hostName
        $objHostSetting["HostType"] = $hostType
        $objHostSetting["NTGroupName"] = $ntGroupName
        $objHostSetting["AuthTrusted"] = $authTrusted
        $objHostSetting["IsHost32BitOnly"] = $32BitOnly 
        $objHostSetting["HostTracking"] = $tracking

        $putOptions = new-Object System.Management.PutOptions
        $putOptions.Type = [System.Management.PutType]::UpdateOnly; # This tells WMI it's an update.

        [Type[]] $targetTypes = New-Object System.Type[] 1
        $targetTypes[0] = $putOptions.GetType()

        $sysMgmtAssemblyName = "System.Management"
        $sysMgmtAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName($sysMgmtAssemblyName)
        $objHostSettingType = $sysMgmtAssembly.GetType("System.Management.ManagementObject")

        [Reflection.MethodInfo] $methodInfo = $objHostSettingType.GetMethod("Put", $targetTypes)
        $methodInfo.Invoke($objHostSetting, $putOptions)

        write-SucessMessage "Host updated"
    }
    catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException]
    {
        write-Error "$hostName host could not be updated: $_.Exception.ToString()"
    }
}

# function to create BizTalk send adapter handler
function Create-Bts-SendHandler([string]$adapter, [string]$hostName)
{
    try
    {
        [System.Management.ManagementObject]$objSendHandler = ([WmiClass]"root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer:MSBTS_SendHandler2").CreateInstance()

        $objSendHandler["AdapterName"] = $adapter
        $objSendHandler["HostName"] = $hostName
        $objSendHandler["IsDefault"] = $false

        $putOptions = new-Object System.Management.PutOptions
        $putOptions.Type = [System.Management.PutType]::CreateOnly;

        [Type[]] $targetTypes = New-Object System.Type[] 1
        $targetTypes[0] = $putOptions.GetType()

        $sysMgmtAssemblyName = "System.Management"
        $sysMgmtAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName($sysMgmtAssemblyName)
        $objSendHandlerType = $sysMgmtAssembly.GetType("System.Management.ManagementObject")

        [Reflection.MethodInfo] $methodInfo = $objSendHandlerType.GetMethod("Put", $targetTypes)
        $methodInfo.Invoke($objSendHandler, $putOptions)

        write-SucessMessage "Send handler created for $adapter / $hostName"
    }
    catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException]
    {
        write-Error "Send handler for $adapter / $hostName could not be created: $_.Exception.ToString()"
    }
}

# function to create BizTalk receive adapter handler
function Create-Bts-ReceiveHandler([string]$adapter, [string]$hostName)
{
    try
    {
        [System.Management.ManagementObject]$objReceiveHandler = ([WmiClass]"root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer:MSBTS_ReceiveHandler").CreateInstance()

        $objReceiveHandler["AdapterName"] = $adapter
        $objReceiveHandler["HostName"] = $hostName

        $putOptions = new-Object System.Management.PutOptions
        $putOptions.Type = [System.Management.PutType]::CreateOnly;

        [Type[]] $targetTypes = New-Object System.Type[] 1
        $targetTypes[0] = $putOptions.GetType()

        $sysMgmtAssemblyName = "System.Management"
        $sysMgmtAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName($sysMgmtAssemblyName)
        $objReceiveHandlerType = $sysMgmtAssembly.GetType("System.Management.ManagementObject")

        [Reflection.MethodInfo] $methodInfo = $objReceiveHandlerType.GetMethod("Put", $targetTypes)
        $methodInfo.Invoke($objReceiveHandler, $putOptions)

        write-SucessMessage "Receive handler created for $adapter / $hostName"
    }
    catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException]
    {
        write-Error "Receive handler for $adapter / $hostName could not be created: $_.Exception.ToString()"
    }
}

# function to create BizTalk host instance
function Create-Bts-Instance([string]$hostName, [string]$login, [string]$password, [string]$Server)
{
    try
    {
        [System.Management.ManagementObject]$objServerHost = ([WmiClass]"root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer:MSBTS_ServerHost").CreateInstance()

        $objServerHost["HostName"] = $hostName
        $objServerHost["ServerName"] = $Server
        $objServerHost.Map()

        [System.Management.ManagementObject]$objHostInstance = ([WmiClass]"root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer:MSBTS_HostInstance").CreateInstance()

        $name = "Microsoft BizTalk Server " + $hostName + " " + $Server
        $objHostInstance["Name"] = $name
        $objHostInstance.Install($Login, $Password, $True)

        write-SucessMessage "Created host instance for $hostName on $Server"
    }
    catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException]
    {
        write-Error "$hostName host instance on server $Server could not be created: $_.Exception.ToString()"
    }
}

function Start-Bts-HostInstance ( [string] $HostName, [string] $Server )
{
    try
    {
        $filter = "HostName = '" + $HostName + "' and RunningServer = '" + $Server + "'"
        $HostInstance = get-wmiobject "MSBTS_HostInstance" -namespace "root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer" -filter $filter
        $HostInstanceState = $HostInstance.GetState().State

        write-InfoMessage "Current state of $HostName instance on server $Server: $HostInstanceState (1=Stopped, 2=Start pending, 3=Stop pending, 4=Running, 8=Unknown)"

        if ($HostInstanceState -eq 1) 
        {
            $HostInstance.Start() 
            $HostInstanceState = $HostInstance.GetState().State
            write-SucessMessage "New state of $HostName instance on server $Server: $HostInstanceState (1=Stopped, 2=Start pending, 3=Stop pending, 4=Running, 8=Unknown)"
        }
        else
        {
            $HostInstanceState = $HostInstance.GetState().State
            write-WarnMessage "Failed to start host instance $HostName on server $Server because host instance state $HostInstanceState was not the expected value of 1 (stopped)"
        }
    }
    catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException]
    {
        write-Error "$hostName host instance could not be started on $Server : $_.Exception.ToString()"
    }
}

function Install-BTSMsi ( [string]$bts_application, [string]$msi_package, [string]$install_env ) 
{
    write-InfoMessage "Installing $msi_package in $bts_application for $install_env"

    BTSTask ImportApp /ApplicationName:$bts_application /Package:$msi_package /Overwrite /Environment:$install_env

    if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
        write-ErrorMessage "Failed to Import MSI $msi_package"
    } 
    else
    {
        write-SucessMessage "Installed $bts_application for $install_env"
    }
}

function Remove-BTSApplication  ( [string]$appServer, [string]$appDatabase, [string]$appName ) 
{
    write-InfoMessage "Uninstalling Application: $appName "
    BTSTask RemoveApp /Server:"$appServer" /ApplicationName:"$appName" /Database:"$appDatabase"  #| out-null

    if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
        write-ErrorMessage "Failed to remove $appServer $appName"
    }
    else
    {
        write-SucessMessage "Removed $appName from $appServer"
    }
} 

# Accesses SSO and will require the build user account to belong to the SSO Admins group. 
# Also requires Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM.dll to be loaded.
function StartStop-BTSApplication ( [string]$appServer, [string]$appName, [string]$appCommand ) 
{ 
    if ( ($appName -eq '') -or ($appName -eq $null) )
    {
        throw 'you must supply the application name'
    }

    #write-InfoMessage " Finding Application: $appServer:$appName "
    $exp = New-Object Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM.BtsCatalogExplorer
    $exp.ConnectionString = Get-BTSConnectionString($appServer) 
    $app = $exp.Applications[$appName] 

    if($app -eq $null) 
    { 
        if ($appCommand -eq "stop" )
        {
            write-WarnMessage "WARNING failed to stop $appName"
        }
        else
        {
            write-WarnMessage "FAILED to start $appName"
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        switch -wildcard ( $app.Status.ToString() )
        {
            'Stopped' 
            {
                if ($appCommand -eq "start" ) {
                    write-InfoMessage "Starting Application: $appName "
                    $null = $app.Start([Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM.ApplicationStartOption]::StartAll) 
                    $null = $exp.SaveChanges() 
                    write-SucessMessage " Started Application: $appName "
                } else {
                    write-InfoMessage "Application Already Stopped: $appName "
                }
            } 
            '*Started' 
            { 
                # includes Started and PartiallyStarted
                if ($appCommand -eq "stop" ) {
                    write-InfoMessage "Stopping Application: $appName "
                    $null = $app.Stop([Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM.ApplicationStopOption]::StopAll) 
                    $null = $exp.SaveChanges() 
                    write-SucessMessage " Stopped Application: $appName "
                } else {
                    write-InfoMessage "Application Already Started : $appName "
                }
            }
            'NotApplicable' 
            {
                write-InfoMessage "Application doesn't require $appCommand"
            } 
            default
            {
                $msg = "Unkown STATUS: " + $app.Status
                write-ErrorMessage $msg
            }
        }
    }
}

function Get-BTSConnectionString ( [string] $server )
{
    $group = Get-WmiObject MSBTS_GroupSetting -n root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer -computername $server
    $grpdb = $group.MgmtDBName
    $grpsvr = $group.MgmtDBServerName
    [System.String]::Concat("server=", $grpsvr, ";database=", $grpdb, ";Integrated Security=SSPI")
    write-InfoMessage " Server: $grpsvr - Database  $grpdb"
}
```

Comment: PS the above scripts will not work with PowerShell 1.0 so upgrade if you want to use them.

Comment: Why the custom `Write-XxxMessage` methods? Why don't you use the builtin `Write-Error`, `Write-Warning`, `Write-Host` etc..?

Comment: `Delete` isn't a supported Verb in PowerShell. If you used the PowerShell convention of Verb-Noun, with only known verbs, these Cmdlet would be called `Remove-BizTalkReceiveHandler`, ... You can lookup the correct verbs using `Get-Verb`.

Answer (score 2):

For 2) you should look into [Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.biztalk.explorerom%28v=bts.20%29.aspx)

Using [ReceiveHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.biztalk.explorerom.receivehandler%28v=bts.20%29.aspx) and [SendHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.biztalk.explorerom.sendhandler%28v=bts.20%29.aspx) should give you what you need.

However there seems to be no way to control host instances, only hosts, using ExplorerOM.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have a script to do the hosts. Uses MSBTS_HostSetting in WMI. I can't get it to work with host instances though.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you borrowed from Santhosh Benjamin's scripts to submit the PutOptions using reflection:

```
    [Type[]] $targetTypes = New-Object System.Type[] 1
    $targetTypes[0] = $putOptions.GetType()
    $sysMgmtAssemblyName = “System.Management”
    $sysMgmtAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName($sysMgmtAssemblyName)
    $objHostSettingType = $sysMgmtAssembly.GetType(“System.Management.ManagementObject”)
    [Reflection.MethodInfo] $methodInfo = $objHostSettingType.GetMethod(“Put”,$targetTypes)
    $methodInfo.Invoke($objHostSetting,$putOptions)
```

I tested this with several scripts I am currently working at, and found out (through sheer stubbernness) that you can simply use the Put method on the object, just as you were used to in C#:

```
    $objHostSetting.Put($putOptions)
```

Cheers,
Charles.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you can't use the Powershell library itself, nothing is stopping you from examining its source to see what it does to perform those functions, which is to interact with the Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM assembly.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I feel that you are missing the point slightly though. I was asking for powershell samples, not C# samples, of which I can find many.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a very useful blog by [Sandro Pereira](http://sandroaspbiztalkblog.wordpress.com/2013/09/05/powershell-to-configure-biztalk-server-host-and-host-instances-according-to-some-of-the-best-practices/) with functions for handling hosts, host instances and adapter handlers

And also [Tomas Restrepo](https://github.com/tomasr/bts-ps-scripts) set on GitHub

The one they didn't seem to cover was deleting a BizTalk host ...

```
function Remove-BizTalkHost(
    [string] $hostName)
{
    try
    {
        $strQuery = "MSBTS_HostSetting.Name='$hostName'";
        $objPath = New-Object System.Management.ManagementPath
        $objPath.Path = $strQuery

        [System.Management.ManagementObject]$objHostSetting = ([WmiClass]"root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer:MSBTS_HostSetting").CreateInstance()
        $objHostSetting.Path = $objPath

        $objHostSetting.Delete()

        Write-Host "Host $hostName was successfully deleted" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
    }
    catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException]
    {
        if ($_.Exception.Message.Contains("No instance was found with the specified key") -eq $true)
        {
            Write-Host "$hostName can't be deleted because already removed from the BizTalk group." -ForegroundColor DarkRed
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Error "$hostName host could not be deleted: $_.Exception.ToString()"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Delete` isn't a supported Verb in PowerShell. If you used the PowerShell convention of Verb-Noun, with only known verbs, this Cmdlet would be called `Remove-BizTalkHost`. You can lookup the correct verbs using `Get-Verb`.